# Distinct Clause not working in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have so many records having duplicate taskid assigned to multiple person, but i want to show distinct records means only one taskid in output in SQL

Below is my query not working give me solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    taskid, taskname, person, userid, dept, date, status, monitor, 
    comments, monitor_comments, respondtime, assignedby, 
    reassigncomment, priority,date_complete, followup_date, re_status
FROM
    task
WHERE     
    (status IS NULL)
```

Comment: DISTINCT works on the whole selected row, not just the first selected column. When there's several rows with same taskid, how do you want to chose the other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added a column priority in which the value of that column is 1 of same TASKID and other will be 0 so i can find

SELECT DISTINCT 
    taskid, taskname, person, userid, dept, date, status, monitor, 
    comments, monitor_comments, respondtime, assignedby, 
    reassigncomment, priority,date_complete, followup_date, re_status
FROM
    task
WHERE
    (status IS NULL) and (priority='1')

Answer (score 1):

in your case, result is distinct but not of your desire because you need only distinct task id then you should use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT taskid
FROM         task
WHERE     (status IS NULL)
```

then result would be distinct task ids.

Comment: What about the rest of the desired columns?

Comment: then you should use nested query.

Comment: when task id is assigned to multiple person then it seems quite hard.

Comment: another way is that we can handle it in application like where we want to show task id then show only unique ids... like id: 3 is assigned to 3 person then show id just once but show detail of all person.

Comment: i want all records to display not only taskid

Comment: how could i do "to show task id then show only unique ids... like id: 3 is assigned to 3 person then show id just once but show detail of all person"

Comment: The question is: what if there are three different people? Which one do you show? That's why distinct isn't working now.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have a column called `taskid` in a table called `task`, I think it *should* be unique -- unless it is somehow a slowly changing dimension.

If it is not unique, then you are begging the question:  which row do you want?

In any case, SQL Server 2005 have a function called `row_number()` that can solve your problem:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by taskid order by taskid) as seqnum
      from task
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return one arbitrary row for each `taskid`.  If you have a way of preferring one row over another, then adjust the `order by` clause.